Gerrit trigger loses connection and it fails to reconnect manually
We have a few Jenkins (version 2.319.1) instances. They have Gerrit Trigger (version 2.30.5） installed. In one of the Jenkins, its Trigger occasionally loses connection to our Gerrit server (version 2.13.14). If we manually press the status button in Gerrit Trigger settings to re-connect, it flashes and then is still in red (disconnected). In all cases, it can recover automatically after a short or long period, totally depending on luck. The system log does not give any helpful information.
How can we find the cause and fix the issue?

You can get more logs from a custom logger. Try listening for ALL on com.sonyericsson.hudson.plugins.gerrit.trigger.hudsontrigger.GerritConnectionListener and com.sonymobile.tools.gerrit.gerritevents.GerritConnection. At least attempts to reconnect should be logged.

I add a logger following your instruction and it looks promising. Thanks!

After analyzing the logs, we tried several methods and one of them has been working great so far. We increased the numbers of sshd.batchThreads and sshd.threads in Gerrit configuration.
